# Create Groups using Directory API in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create groups and mailing lists using the Directory API but it seems that there is something wrong. I'm using the code from [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python) and it works fine. But when I'm trying to change the scope to :`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member` in order to create or access groups, I'm getting the following error:

> https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&orderBy=email&alt=json&maxResults=10 returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">

Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: The different scope has been used in the example that you linked ('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'). Maybe this is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of users, as in the line

```
results = service.users().list(customer='my_customer',maxResults=10,orderBy='email').execute()
```

you need the `admin.directory.user` scope. 
If you want to list the users, you need to include the correct scope in the `SCOPES` list. If you don't, removing this line should fix this error. The rest of the example does rely on this line though.

Comment: Actually I can get the list of users. The example I linked works fine. The problem is that I need to modify this example in order to create groups. For this reason I tried to change the scope to : `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member`

Comment: @at91 You can only get the list of users if you have the`admin.directory.user` scope. As soon as you remove this from the list of scopes, the request no longer has access to the list of users (even if the account making the request does) and so you get this error when trying to get the list of users.

Comment: @Davis These are the modifications to the code I'm using. I changed the scope because I'm trying to have access to the groups not the users and it raises an errror.
`SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member']`
  `  service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)`
   ` res= service.groups().list().execute()`

Comment: `<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">` and this is the error I'm getting

Comment: @at91 It looks like you are trying to access the list of groups on your domain. To view this you need the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly` scope or the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group` scope if you want to edit the groups (not group members). For full information on which scopes do what, you can refer to the developer guide provided by google at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#admindirectory_v1. Bear in mind that you will likely need different scopes for different requests.